# how to use ax.get_subplotspec().is_first_col() instead of is_first_col

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried program for machine learning using python but I'm getting a warning as

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\AKASH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\tools.py", line 400
    if ax.is_first_col():
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The is_first_col function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().is_first_col() instead.
```

I referred the code in this link https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/

I think the problem is in the version of matplotlib.

Comment: This is just a warning - apparently pandas needs to change their code a bit (or complain to Matplotlib and argue for re-including the ax.is_first_col method)